# 1046: No database selected?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am having a problem. The below code, I clearly select a database, however it still gives me an error stating I didn't. Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php

$nc = mysqli_connect("localhost", "264191", "adhiambo95");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Sorry I couldn't connect to mysql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_select_db($sc, "264191");

$sis = "INSERT INTO nogata_keywords ('keyword')
    VALUE ('.$_GET[keyword]')";

if (!mysqli_query($nc,$sis))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($nc));
}

else
{
    echo "This keyword has been added to the database.";
}

?>
```

Comment: Please see: Why is $foo[bar] wrong? http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php (A puppy dies when you do this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've misspelled your connection resource variable here:

```
mysqli_select_db($sc, "264191");
```

Should be

```
mysqli_select_db($nc, "264191");
```

---

`mysqli_connect` also allows you to specify your database as the 4th parameter, making the above line redundant:

```
$nc = mysqli_connect("localhost", "264191", "adhiambo95", "264191");
```

Try it out.

---

One more thing, pointed out first by Yogesh Suthar, your SQL query is wrong, you have a period where you shouldn't:

```
$sis = "INSERT INTO nogata_keywords ('keyword') VALUE ('.$_GET[keyword]')";
```

Should be

```
$sis = "INSERT INTO nogata_keywords (`keyword`) VALUE ('".$nc->real_escape_string($_GET['keyword'])."')";
```

Because you have quoted the field name in single quotes and not escaped the value to be inserted into the database. ie if keyword was O'Neil this would invalidate the SQL.

Consider switching to using `prepare()` and `bind()` to avoid this issue.

You should also use 'keyword' as in index to the $_GET array not just keyword which is actually a constant. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: You should fix OP's SQL for a complete answer

Comment: Almost but not quite: `$sis = "INSERT INTO nogata_keywords (keyword) VALUE ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['keyword'])."')";` (I +1'd not downvoted)

Comment: The OP isn't using `mysql`, which by the way is deprecated. Why are you trying to correct me with it? Understood, thank-you.

Comment: because you didn't prepare() bind() and field names dont have single quotes around them (cheers: mysql changed to mysqli)

Answer (score 3):

You are using wrong connection variable $sc it should be $nc

```
mysqli_select_db($nc, "264191");
```

Assumption "264191" is your db name.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error at `$sis`. Anyway, you might need to check if the database is really existed? And you have the proper permission to access it

Comment: Hey, what's the error? I just came across it. It's giving me this: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''keyword') VALUE ('test')' at line 1

Comment: @NatashaHarrell See my answer with query.

Answer (score 0):

you can also pass database name as 4 parameter in `mysqli_connect`

```
mysqli_connect("localhost", "264191", "adhiambo95","264191");
```

Also this

```
$sis = "INSERT INTO nogata_keywords ('keyword')
VALUE ('.$_GET[keyword]')";
       ^^
```

**Edit**

should be

```
$sis = "INSERT INTO nogata_keywords (`keyword`)
VALUE ('$_GET[keyword]')";
```

You used `'` around `keyword`, you have to use `` ` `` around column names

Comment: mysqli: should be `INSERT INTO nogata_keywords (keyword) VALUES (?)` with prepare and bind?

Comment: I did that, but it's yielding the same error: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''keyword') VALUE ('')' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, a proper version, with numerous errors fixed

```
<?php

$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "264191", "adhiambo95", "264191");
if (!$mysqli)
{
    trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO nogata_keywords (keyword) VALUE (?)";
$stm = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or trigger_error($mysqli->error);
$stm->bindParam("s",$_GET['keyword'])  or trigger_error($mysqli->error);
$stm->execute() or trigger_error($mysqli->error);
```